# Spring Boot JDBC microservices cannot connect to MySQL in docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have 2 Spring Boot microservices that need to connect to a MySQL service which itself is deployed in Docker. I'm using Docker Compose but for some reason they cannot reach the DB. I have used the service name in the connection string but still no connection.

Here is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mysqldb:
    container_name: mysqldb
    image: mysql:8
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=eryrty45fgd3DE
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=bank_db
      - MYSQL_USER=java_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=dd0953
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./scripts/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql
  accounts-service:
    container_name: accounts-service
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    build: 
        context: ./accounts-service
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: accounts-service:latest
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - MYSQLDB_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/bank_db?useSSL=false
      - MYSQLDB_USER=java_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=dd0953
      - NOTIFY_SERVICE_URL=http://notify-service:8002
    volumes:
      - servs:/tmp
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  transactions-service:
    container_name: transactions-service
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
      - accounts-service
      - notify-service
    build: 
        context: ./transaction-service
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: transactions-service:latest
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
    environment:
      - MYSQLDB_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/bank_db?useSSL=false
      - MYSQLDB_USER=java_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=dd0953
      - NOTIFY_SERVICE_URL=http://notify-service:8002
      - ACCOUNT_SERVICE_URL=http://accounts-service:8000
    volumes:
      - servs:/tmp
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  notify-service:
    container_name: notify-service
    build: 
        context: ./notification-service
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: notify-service:latest
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8002:8002
    volumes:
      - servs:/tmp
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
volumes:
  db:
  servs:
```

Here is my connection string:

```
    spring.datasource.url:jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/bank_db?useSSL=false
```

The stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
accounts-service        |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
accounts-service        |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
accounts-service        |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
accounts-service        |   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
accounts-service        |   at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
accounts-service        |   at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
accounts-service        |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
accounts-service        |   at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar!/:8.0.28]
accounts-service        |   ... 127 common frames omitted
```

Comment: My first guess is that your applications are probably trying to connect to mysql before mysql is ready to accept connections. However, with `restart: on-failure`, that should resolve itself by restarting the container until it works. Is that not happening?

Comment: no its not connecting when db is up

Comment: did you configure the spring datasource user in you application.properties accordingly?
Or do you use your own variables  (which you overwrite in your compose file) to configure the connection mannually?

Comment: yes I did and i'm guessing if the issue was credentials I should get access denied error.

Comment: looks like its a mysql issue. i have logged into the container with 

 ` docker-compose exec mysqldb /bin/bash  `  and tried to login to the mysql but i'm getting access denied with the credentials on the docker compose file. but the mysqldb service config seem fine to me unless i'm missing something

Comment: Your yaml file contains a lot of duplicates - is it just copy/paste issue and the real file is OK, or the real file also contains duplicates?

Comment: its not duplicates there are 3 services each with its own configs

Comment: Are these not duplicates? At the beginning of the file you: "version: "3.8"
services:
  mysqldb: ... + 3 services". And after that the following lines appear twice
 "volumes:
  db:
  servs:version: "3.8"
services:
  mysqldb: .... and other 3 services".

Comment: aah yea its a typo edited it